# NODE JS Passing characters in get request

Tags: sql, node.js, get, sql-server-express

I am using Node and Express with MSNODESQLV8 to write an API demo (my first) to get some rows from a remote SQL Server instance. My other get queries work fine when searching for an ID which is a number but I am unsure how to pass a value in the form of characters to a parameter in my query. Pretty sure `req.params.id` is not appropriate.

```
app.get("/productsname/:id", (req, res) => {
    const productName = req.params.id;
    const productsNameQuery = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductName = ?";
    sql.query(connStr, productsNameQuery, [productName], (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(`Failed to get product by id ${req.params.id}. ${err}`);
            res.sendStatus(500);
        }else {
            res.json(rows);
        }
    })
});
```

I want to take a product name (string?) in at the end of the url where it reads "id" and pass it as a value to the productName const. The end goal is to retrieve all rows from the SQL table where the product name is "processor" in the get url (`http://localhost:2000/productname/proccesor`). Perhaps I am passing the url incorrectly?

Apologies if this is really basic. I am very new to this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are using productname in url instead of productsname define in app.get

Comment: Apologies. I don't quite understand. How would I pass "processor" value as a parameter to the query? The idea is an app would append "processor" to the end of the url for the 'GET' request. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You have to use this url http://localhost:2000/productsname/proccesor

Comment: Syntax error. Thanks for your help. I should have been more observant.